# How to convert pixel value into scale? in Javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming

I Have to create page width in zoom operation

So I have few options

```
<select id="scaleSelect" class="scale selectpicker" title="Zoom" onchange="zoomval();">
<option title="" value="I have to convert the page width to scale value"  id="page_fit">Page Width</option>
          <option title="" value="0.5"  >50%</option>
          <option title="" value="0.75">75%</option>
          <option title="" value="1">100%</option>
          <option title="" value="1.25">125%</option>
          <option title="" value="1.5">150%</option>
          <option title="" value="2">200%</option>
          <option title="" value="3">300%</option>
          <!-- <option title="" value="4">400%</option> -->
          </select>
```

I have calculated screen width (1366px) , Now I have to convert in to scale and I have to use for page width option.

How can I able to do this?

```
function zoomval(){
  console.log("Value changing")
  var page_f_val = $('#page_fit').val();
  var page_fit = $("#scaleSelect").val();
  if(page_fit == page_f_val){
    console.log("Value Matched")
    $('#viewer > div').map(function() 
        {       
    console.log(this.id)
    var pagecontainter_val = document.getElementById(this.id)
    console.log(pagecontainter_val)
    $("#"+this.id).css({"width":"100%"});

            //  if($("#"+this.id+"  #pdf-annotate-edit-overlay").length > 0)
            //  {
            //   document.getElementById(this.id).removeChild(document.getElementById('pdf-annotate-edit-overlay'));
            //  }
        });
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom in or zoom out using css property

```js
var max = 2, min=0.5,curZoom = 1;
function zoom(inc){
  curZoom+=(inc*0.1);
  $("#zoomable").css('zoom',curZoom);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='zoomable'><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/wisconsin.svg"></div>


<button onclick='zoom(1)'>Zoom In</button>
<button onclick='zoom(-1)'>Zoom Out</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. But I have to change the value based upon the different screen.. For example mine is 1366px how to convert into scale value  like  1 or 1.2

Comment: what is the base value from which you want to convert or take a ratio?

Comment: am taking screen resolution and am converting

Comment: var x = "Total Width: " + screen.width + "px";
  var bodyWidth = 1000;
  var screenwidth = screen.width;
  console.log(x);
  if (screenwidth < bodyWidth)
       scale = 1
    else {
       scale = screenwidth / bodyWidth; 
    }
    console.log(scale)
    $('#page_fit').val(scale).trigger('change');

Comment: you are doing correctly. So what is the problem occurring?

Comment: am getting scroll on bottom .. Is that ok?? Because that image is too big

Comment: if you don't want scroll you can use height 100% or width 100% this will maintain the aspect ratio. But if you don't want to maintain the aspect ratio use width 100% and height 100%

Comment: Yes I have changed width 100% in inspect But I have to set using jquery .. But Its not happening .. I have updated my code.. But nothing happened

Comment: No I could not .. Its big files am using pdf.js for viewer